# Git partial commit of changes

Tags: git

Assume a single file gets a few changes related to different issues. We can easily just post git commit with a note to describe each change for each issue, push that, and remind ourselves not to do that again.

Depending on how complex the changes are, I use this pattern to give each change its own commit:

1. Copy the finished working file to a new Final file.
2. Revert the working file back to its last commit state.
3. Diff the working file and the Final file, and hand-merge individual lines for an issue.
4. Commit with a clean comment for a single issue.
5. Repeat as required.
6. Delete the Final file as it's now just a copy of the current working file.

Is there a better way to do this, other than "don't do that"? In short, I'm cherry-picking within a single file. But as any developer knows, changes can spread across multiple files, and sometimes it's difficult to avoid making a change right now when we're looking right at a line that needs to be changed, compared to flagging it and coming back later for a dedicated change/commit. Thanks.

Comment: Do you work with branches? The reality is this whole post makes my head throb and I use Git daily. If you are trying to note  specific commit means something in a linear way, that defeats the purpose of Git. [Read up on “git flow” and why branches are the best way you can use Git](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's basically the purpose of Git's "staging area". Commits do not actually store the working tree, but only changes that you've copied to the staging area. You've already used `git add` to stage individual files in preparation for a commit, but it also allows more fine-grained operations. See for example [Chapter 7.2](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging) in the Git Book.

The usual pattern is to use `git add -p` to select individual diff hunks, with the ability to <kbd>e</kbd>dit them further (e.g. in case you have unrelated lines in the same hunk). There is also a corresponding `git reset -p` to *unstage* individual changes in case you've added too much.

Use `git diff --cached` to see what's staged. Finally just run `git commit` as usual.

*(If you want a shortcut, `git commit -p` does everything in one step.)*

You can also run `git gui` or `git citool` to get a graphical commit interface, which has the ability to select individual lines with a mouse (right-click to stage). It's also built in to most other graphical Git clients. However, these usually only work at whole-line level – if your file has unrelated changes within the same line, you'll still have to use *git add -p* and hand-edit the patch.

Comment: I do sometimes unstage some changes for one commit, then come back to stage others, essentially getting a few consecutive commits from one updated workspace. But you've provided exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for. I'll try your suggestion, report back here, and will check this as the answer if all goes well. Thanks.